# PHP-FPM using too much memory

Tags: php, php-fpm

I have a VPS box that runs a few websites for me as well as some scripts and it seems like its running out of memory. It has 1GB total memory. It looks like php-fpm exhausts the memory. Before it was simply killing other processes (like mysql) to free memory.

The error was:

```
php fpm has invoked oom-killer
```

I solved that using this solution: [php-fpm invokes oom-killer](https://serverfault.com/questions/344525/php-fpm-invokes-oom-killer/344671#344671)

Next I tried to configure various php-fpm settings with no luck. I also increased my swap file size from 1GB to 2GB (2x my physical memory). I am running a total of 10 small websites which don't get much traffic at all so I'm confused why I am running out of memory. Besides purchasing more memory for my box, is there anything else I can do?

At this point php-fpm seems to hog up the entire 1GB of memory and most of the swap, in some cases it stops me from accessing the VPS as I can't authenticate!

Running a:

```
service php-fpm restart
```

Instantly frees up almost all the memory on the box (ie 950/990 in use goes to 200/990 in use). So what are my options? I can also post relevant configuration files if needed.

Relevant specs:
OS: Centos 6.7 x86_64
RAM: 1GB
Swap: 2GB
php -version: PHP 5.5.35 (cli) (built: Apr 29 2016 09:07:44)
php-fpm -version: PHP 5.5.35 (fpm-fcgi) (built: Apr 29 2016 09:09:09)

Comment: Which of the fpm process managers are you running? You will generally want to run `ondemand` in cases like that. `dynamic` or `static` will kill you on a box with that little memory and more then one pool, as the spare processes will eat all your precious memory.

Comment: It was on dynamic, I am now trying ondemand to see if it improves the situation, looks promising.

Answer (score 3):

(this should be a comment but its a bit long).

"I solved that using this solution" - unfortunately most of the opinions there are wrong.

`php fpm has invoked oom-killer`

This means that:

1. your system is configured to overcommit memory. Memory overcommit is useful when you have to manage badly written, long-running processes written in object oriented languages (like Java) and for vm hosts running large numbers of inactive guests. Neither seems to apply here. Setting the overcommit_memory to 2 as suggested will disable overcommit - so WTF does Chris suggest setting the overcommit_ratio to 80% (default usually about 50%) when it is disabled???
2. PHP-FPM asked for more memory and there was none left. That doesn't necessarily mean that PHP-FPM used up all the memory.

Your problem is that the config your are using does not fit in the box you are using. But describing [how to configure Linux, PHP, MySQL and a webserver](https://www.google.co.in/books/edition/Linux_Apache_MySQL_PHP_Performance_End_t/Z3ciBgAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1) is somewhat off topic here.

That restarting the FPM process seems to resolve the issue **suggests** that the problem is PHP-FPM, but it's no smoking gun. Maybe each PHP process has an open database connection.

Since you've not posted you php-fpm config nor provided any details of your webserver, nor given any metrics about response time, this question can't be answered here.

Either spend a lot of time and effort learning how to measure your systems behavour and tune it, or buy more memory.

Comment: that link is useless

Comment: overcommit_ratio: When overcommit_memory is set to 2, the committed address
space is not permitted to exceed swap plus this percentage
of physical RAM. Source: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/sysctl/vm.txt